# Proof of supremum and infemum of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Is the following true:

$\sup(f+g)\ge \sup(f)+\inf (g)$?

If so prove it.

I think its true, but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: consider $\sup(f+\inf(g))$ compared with the two expressions you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $x$ in the domain of the functions, so that: $$f(x) + \inf g \leq f(x) + g(x)  = (f+g)(x)\leq \sup (f+g), \quad \forall x.$$This directly yields $\sup f + \inf g \leq \sup(f+g)$. You can think that: $$f(x) \leq \sup(f+g) - \inf g, \quad \forall x,$$so you can take $\sup$ in the left side and then rearrange.